# How to create abnormal amount of subdirs?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to create 1000x1000x1000x1000x1000, etc. directories, but something like `mkdir -p {1..1000}/{1..1000}/{1..1000}/{1..1000}` gives *to many arguments* error or just infinitely eats my RAM... How can I do it properly?

Comment: The question is tagged `sh` and `bash`. This `{1..1000}` syntax you tried to use works in Bash, it does not work in pure `sh`. Does the `sh` tag mean you want solutions that use POSIX shell syntax only?

Comment: you want a trillion directories? or even a quadrillion? in the case of `{1..1000}` requires 4MB just for the folders -  `{1..1000}/{1..1000}` requires 4GB, now I haven't tried going further, but it seems to be that  `{1..1000}/{1..1000}/{1..1000}` would be in the realms of 4TB, one level deeper and you're in PETAbyte territory, and 5 levels deep, you'll be in exabyte territory - this is using ext4, not sure about other filesystems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested `for` loops should work.

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
    for j in {1..1000}
    do
        for k in {1..1000}
        do
            for m in {1..1000}
            do
                mkdir -p $i/$j/$k/$m
            done
        done
    done
done
```

There may be a better/faster way to do it (it took a full 10 sec to create **{1..10}** folders, 4 levels deep, on the low-end x86 box I tested it on), but this *should* work even to large numbers of directories, because it's only creating 4 directories (max) per `mkdir` execution.

This syntax doesn't work with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) versions older than 3.0, but you could use `for i in $(seq 1 1000)` or `for (( i=1; i<=1000; i++ ))` instead.

**Additional context**, in case you're wondering why `mkdir -p {1..1000}/{1..1000}/{1..1000}/{1..1000}` yields a "too many arguments" or memory error -- when you use that syntax, the shell expands the argument list *before* passing it to the command.

For example, `echo {1..10}/{1..10}` returns this (100 args):

```
1/1 1/2 1/3 1/4 1/5 1/6 1/7 1/8 1/9 1/10 2/1 2/2 2/3 2/4 2/5 2/6 2/7 2/8 2/9 2/10 3/1 3/2 3/3 3/4 3/5 3/6 3/7 3/8 3/9 3/10 4/1 4/2 4/3 4/4 4/5 4/6 4/7 4/8 4/9 4/10 5/1 5/2 5/3 5/4 5/5 5/6 5/7 5/8 5/9 5/10 6/1 6/2 6/3 6/4 6/5 6/6 6/7 6/8 6/9 6/10 7/1 7/2 7/3 7/4 7/5 7/6 7/7 7/8 7/9 7/10 8/1 8/2 8/3 8/4 8/5 8/6 8/7 8/8 8/9 8/10 9/1 9/2 9/3 9/4 9/5 9/6 9/7 9/8 9/9 9/10 10/1 10/2 10/3 10/4 10/5 10/6 10/7 10/8 10/9 10/10
```

...so with a four-level directory structure (as in the example), you're **effectively passing** 1000*1000*1000*1000 = ***1 trillion* arguments** to `mkdir`.

On my system, the default configuration is to permit just over 2 million <strike>arguments</strike> *bytes* in an argument list; you can check yours with `getconf ARG_MAX`. Since each argument consumes at least 3 bytes (`1/1`), the limit would be encountered by the time ~700,000 arguments were passed.

Comment: Side note: `ARG_MAX` is not the maximum for argument count, it's for size. I don't know if null terminators and such count in Linux, nevertheless a path like `1/1` takes at least 3 bytes, this is what counts towards the limit; plus the environment. The standard error message when the limit is exceeded is `argument list too long`, not `too many arguments`. Resources advise reducing the number of arguments because this is something one can usually do (and e.g. call `mkdir` many times), while reducing the length of each is not that easy; but under the hood it's all about the size, not the count.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @KamilMaciorowski, I had forgotten that `ARG_MAX` refers to the `sizeof` the arglist. FWIW, I was just quoting the OP when I referenced `too many arguments`. Ultimately, my point remains the same about the way args are expanded :)